# ActiveAndroid how to create largen than query

Tags: android, activeandroid

I started to use ActiveAndroid.
I have a lot of users, and it isn't clear for me from docs how can I make a query to select all users where their age is larger than criteria?

Comment: Do you know sql? have you check the doc? https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Querying-the-database

Comment: Yes, but I can just find queries like this:
return new Select()
        .from(User.class)
        .where("age = ?", user.getAge())
        .orderBy("RANDOM()")
        .executeSingle();
but how can I get a list from users e.g. with age larger than 18?

Comment: .where("age >  ?", ageLimit)

Comment: thanks. thats work.